# Cell value of a datagrid in mvvm

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid

How to get the cell value of a datagrid in MVVM.i am not selecting anything just i want the value of 2nd row first column.

Comment: How are you loading your datagrid??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally your Datagrind is bound to a Property on your Viewmodel. simply access that Property in your Viewmodel and get the Values you need.

In ViewModel you have a Property:

```
 public ObservableCollection<Characteristic> Items{get;set;}
```

Characteristics Class

```
public class Characteristic : ObservableObject
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

}
```

In XAML:

```
  <DataGrid Margin="0" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="True" />
```

You just access the Items Property on your ViewModel and get the second item of the Collection.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let me try.

Comment: var snd = Items[1]; //2nd row